# How could this Project euler question be written in mathematica?

Tags: project-euler

I defined `a`,`b`,`c` as `a=m^2-n^2`, `b=2m*n` and `c=m^2+n^2` because of Euclids formula it makes all triplets. however how can I go forward from here?
could I have some advice on how to solve it instead of the answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a forum for PE questions/answers (per rules of PE site)

Comment: how can I reformulate this question so it doesn't close?

Comment: Given the rules of PE I'm not sure it is possible. They do not want answers posted on the internet.

Comment: could I have some advice on how to solve it instead of the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python code to calculate the problem is as follows:

```python
import os
import numpy as np



def solve(N):
    L_arr = np.ones((N+1,), dtype=int)
    for m in range(2,int((N/2)**.5)+1):
        for n in range(1,m):
            if not (m+n)%2: continue #m+n is not odd -> no right triangle here
            if np.gcd(m,n) != 1: continue #not coprime -> no right triangle here
            L = 2*m * (n + m)
            L_arr[L::L] -= 1 #if a given position is only decremented once, count_nonzero will pick it up

    return N+1 - np.count_nonzero(L_arr)
    

print(solve(1500000))
```

But the code of Mathematica version has a slight problem, and I'll fix it later.

```
Num = 150;
arr = ConstantArray[1, Num + 1];
For[m = 2, m <= Floor[Sqrt[Num/2] + 1], m++, 
 For[n = 1, n <= m, n++, 
  If[! OddQ[m + n], If[GCD[m, n] != 1, L = Min[2*m*(n + m), Num];
    arr[[L+1 ;; All ;; L]] = arr[[L+1 ;; All ;; L]] - 1]]]]
Num + 1 - Count[arr, u_ /; u != 0]
```

Comment: I wrote my code in Java but i had problems converting it to Mathematica as well!

Comment: L = 1500
Solve[ a + b + c = 
  L && a^2 + b^2 + c^2 && & a > 0 && & b > 0 && & c > 0]

Comment: i was wondering if Solve can be used for generating the triplets seperated by &&, im just not sure how to iterate it

Comment: `Table[
 Map[Sort, 
   Solve[a + b + c == L && a^2 + b^2 == c^2 && a > 0 && b > 0 && 
      c > 0, Integers] // Values] // DeleteDuplicates, {L, 12, 150}]`

Comment: thanks! I get a weird output that comes out as a list, how can I show how many one integer sided right angle triangles there are from the codee? I used Count however it gave me two seperate lists as outputs